# My app's icon is still default when I upload to the android market

Tags: android, google-play

Hey everyone, when I run my app on my phone the icon shows up as the one I want it to be, the one i placed in the drawable folder in eclipse. However, when I upload the app to google, the apps icon is still the default android icon. How come it is doing this?

this is in my androidmanifest.xml:
application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: Have uploaded the build with icon? i mean is that final build you are uploading to market.

Comment: All I uploaded was the. Apk file. Isn't the icon included in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the icon to these three folders under you project:

1. drawable-hdpi
2. drawable-mdpi
3. drawable-ldpi

The resolution of the icons should be:

1. 72 * 72 px
2. 48 * 48 px
3. 36 * 36 px respectively

If the icon you want is not present, it will revert to the original default icon.

You could also read the Android Icon Guidelines here (specifically the "Size and positioning" section): [Icon Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)